# How do I create an “between” Condition filter on integer field using elasticsearch-dsl-py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, dsl

The query below is what I would like to construct using elasticsearch-dsl-py, but I do not know how to do it.

```
GET /myindex/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "int_field": {
        "gte": "2455",
        "lte": "2455"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*I just want to execute a query like below in SQL format*

```
select * from my_index where int_field >= 777 or int_field <= 779
```

**Using elasticsearch-dsl-py, this is as close as I can get, but it is not the same.**

```
class MyIndex(Document):

    int_field = Integer()
    
    

MyIndex.search().filter('range', int_field={"gte": 2454,"lte": 2456})
```

**Above code gives below error**

> {   "error": {
> "root_cause": [
> {
> "type": "query_shard_exception",
> "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  "range" : {\n    "int_field" : {\n      "from" : 2454,\n      "to" : 2456,\n
> "include_lower" : false,\n      "include_upper" : true,\n
> "boost" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
> "index_uuid": "HRdIrs3LRnqO_5rbSjZi7A",
> "index": "myindex"
> }
> ],
> "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
> "reason": "all shards failed",
> "phase": "query",
> "grouped": true,
> "failed_shards": [
> {
> "shard": 0,
> "index": "myindex",
> "node": "t-bkDruUSh61vUvKAlX2fw",
> "reason": {
> "type": "query_shard_exception",
> "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  "range" : {\n    "int_field" : {\n      "from" : 2454,\n      "to" : 2456,\n
> "include_lower" : false,\n      "include_upper" : true,\n
> "boost" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
> "index_uuid": "HRdIrs3LRnqO_5rbSjZi7A",
> "index": "myindex",
> "caused_by": {
> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason": "Cannot search on field [int_field] since it is not indexed."
> }
> }
> }
> ]   },   "status": 400 }

Comment: Your query is correct, however, it seems that the field `int_field` is not indexed, hence it's not searchable. Can you share what you get from `GET myindex`?

Comment: @Val it is in index with multiple documents. while checking _mapping it gives ```"char_end" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "index" : false
        },```

is it possible because of **index: false** ?

Comment: You need to set `"index": true` instead of `"index": false` and then your query will work